# unity doesn't load showing error

Tags: unity

My pc has a graphic card less than 100mb can still ubuntu 13.10 work.I got a answer of previous question of installing ccsm but it shows error pakage data not found how to fix this issue

Comment: post the full error report.

Comment: what graphics card ?  What error message are you getting ?

Comment: After running command it shows reading pakage lists....done
building dependency tree
reading state information....done
E:unable to locate package compizconfig-setting-manager
E:unable to locate package compiz-plugins -extra-y

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update` recently?

Answer (score 0):

Run this command to install compiz in ubuntu 13.10,

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins-extra -y
```

Logout and login back.